# "Invalid Token" on Apple Push Notification

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We can't get the Apple Push Notification to work on Azure Mobile Services. We've uploaded the production certificate and tried sending, but each time it returns an "Invalid Token" error. Sample device token that we pass is 'g4eaa50c3fdc3b97dc7ff0b4e745593e7b9bdae36d6e4ca78e4146a086c5be1a'.

Please help.

Comment: How are you getting the sample device token? It is likely not a valid production token.

Comment: This token you're passing is invalid - the device token should be a hex representation of a `NSData` (received in the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method), and the first letter `g` doesn't belong in such representation (valid characters: [0-9a-f]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app delegate of your app write the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];  
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    NSLog(@"Device Token === %@", deviceTokenString);
}



- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"Error in getting Device Token === %@", error);
}
```

Then run your app on a device. When you do so, you will be asked for permission to display Push Messages from your application. If you allow, then the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get called and your device token will be printed on the console.